# How to insert multi-size icon file using RC.EXE?

Tags: delphi

I created a multi-sized icon file for my application. Now i'm using a .rc file to link the icon to my app. Here is the contents of my .rc file :

MAINICON ICON myapp.ico

The file is compiled by RC.EXE, but no icon is added into my application; it keeps using the default Delphi's icon :

[image]

What am i missing ?

Thanks

Comment: If you rename the icon in the RC file (to `MYICON`, say), you will see that it is included in the EXE. But I think the IDE will insist on inserting the icon from the Project Options dialog.

Comment: Have you tried to build the app without using the IDE?

Comment: This works, at least temporarily: (1) Make sure the project is NOT opened in any IDE. (2) Open the *.dproj file in a text editor. (3) Remove the `<Icon_MainIcon>` line(s). (4) Save the file. (5) Open the project in the IDE. (6) Build it. (7) Now, the IDE will not insert its own icon, so your icon specified in the RC file becomes the application icon.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Wow, that worked ! Is it some kind of bug in Delphi 11 ? Thanks a lot, please post (again) as answer, this is valuable info lol. You made my day !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon you specify in your *.rc file *does* indeed get included in the EXE, as you can easily verify using a resource editor. However, if you build using the IDE, so does the icon specified in the Project Options, and that one becomes the main icon of the application.

I almost would expect the Project Options dialog box to have some option *not* to include an icon, but I cannot find any such option. You can add or change the icon, but you cannot remove it if it is already there.

However, it seems like you can remove it yourself by editing the *.dproj file behind the back of the IDE:

1. Make sure the project is NOT opened in any instance of the Rad Studio IDE.
2. Open the *.dproj file in a text editor.
3. Remove the `<Icon_MainIcon>` line(s).
4. Save the file.

Now, if you open the project in the IDE and build it, the IDE will *not* insert any icon, so your icon specified in the *.rc file becomes the application icon.